# Validate xml attributes of unknown element with xsd

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, any

I'm using an xsd to validate xml files that may have several unknown xml elements.
I know that xsd supports the "any" element for processing unknown xml elements. The problem is that I have to validate the attributes of these unknown elements, and I have not been able to find a way to do so.

Xml dummy example:

```
<root>
   <aaaaaa gui-name="my name" group="my group" chart="my chart" />
   <nnnnnn gui-name="my name" group="my group" chart="my chart" />
   <yyyyyy gui-name="my name" group="my group" chart="my chart" />
   ...
   ...
</root>
```

The xml elements are unknown but their attributes are well known. 
How can I validate the attributes of these unknown elements?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you saying the 'aaaaaaa', 'nnnnnn', and 'yyyyyy' could be anything?  Can you access all children and iterate over then checking attributes instead of trying to access the children by name?  Its hard to give advice without seeing what you are actually doing now

Comment: Those are simply dummy examples of elements but, yes, they can be anything. The point here is that those elements must have the same attributes, and I do have to validate if those attributes are present and if they have valid values. Now I'm not validating those attributes at all. I'm simply using the "any" xsd element which accepts all elements

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `<any>` element type.

see http://www.w3schools.com/Xml/schema_complex_any.asp

```
<xs:element name="root">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:any type='dummyType' />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="dummyType">
  <xs:attribute name='gui-name' type='xs:string'/>
  <xs:attribute name='group' type='xs:string'/>
  <xs:attribute name='chart' type='xs:string'/>

</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the "type" attribute is not allowed in the "any" element.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need implements inheritance by using SubstitutionGroups. Look at the paragraph "Abstract elements and substitution groups" in the next link

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xtendschema/

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion seems to be useful when we know the elements that may appear in the XML. In my case I do not know which elements will appear in the XML. I only know the attributes allowed in those elements.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off changing the XML format. Move the tag name into an attribute, and use the same name for all tags. 
An xsi:type attribute on each tag may be able to identify the name of a complex type that contains the attributes. Have you looked at that possibility?

Comment: Thanks, I do not own the XML, therefore changing its format is out of the question.

Comment: Fair enough. XML Schema has two ways to identify the type. It uses the tag name to identify a type (or a family of types) and/or it uses an xsi:type attribute. In your case, neither technique can be used, so it looks as if this XML format that cannot be described by an XSD.